# Nhibernate/Hibernate, lookup tables and object design

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, object-object-mapping

I've got two tables. Invoice with columns CustomerID, InvoiceDate, Value, InvoiceTypeID (CustomerID and InvoiceDate make up a composite key) and InvoiceType with InvoiceTypeID and InvoiceTypeName columns.

I know I can create my objects like:

```
public class Invoice
{
    public virtual int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Value { get; set; }
    public virtual InvoiceType InvoiceType { get; set; }
}

public class InvoiceType
{
    public virtual InvoiceTypeID { get; set; }
    public virtual InvoiceTypeName { get; set; }
}
```

So the generated sql would look something like:

```
SELECT CustomerID, InvoiceDate, Value, InvoiceTypeID FROM Invoice WHERE CustomerID = x AND InvoiceDate = y
SELECT InvoiceTypeID, InvoiceTypeName FROM InvoiceType WHERE InvoiceTypeID = z
```

But rather that having two select queries executed to retrieve the data I would rather have one. I would also like to avoid using child object for simple lookup lists. So my object would look something like:

```
public class Invoice
{
    public virtual int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Value { get; set; }
    public virtual InvoiceTypeID { get; set; }
    public virtual InvoiceTypeName { get; set; }
}
```

And my sql would look something like:

```
SELECT CustomerID, InvoiceDate, Value, InvoiceTypeID 
FROM Invoice INNER JOIN InvoiceType ON Invoice.InvoiceTypeID = InvoiceType.InvoiceTypeID
WHERE CustomerID = x AND InvoiceDate = y
```

My question is how do I create the mapping for this?

I've tried using join but this tried to join using CustomerID and InvoiceDate, am I missing something obvious?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is (as you said) to avoid two queries, you can retrieve the data using a single HQL statement:

```
select i, it from Invoice i fetch join i.type it where ...
```

...as documented in the hibernate [docs](https://www.hibernate.org/315.html). This should execute only one SQL select statement and retrieve everything without any mapping changes.

This is a regular HQL query and is executed as follows:

```
IQuery q = s.CreateQuery("select i, it from Invoice i fetch join i.type it where ...");
IList invoices = q.List();
```

More information is available on the hibernate query language [page](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/html/queryhql.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how do you actually do this? Where do you specify this HQL? In the mapping? In the code? I still don't understand how to add the lookup table into the mapping. Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my answer with additional code to better explain it. When you need invoice data, you execute such a query in your OO code, yes.